# PySerial dataSend doesn't receive data

Tags: python, c, avr, pyserial, atmel

I want to make a connection between python script and atxmega128a3u avr microcontroller.

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from termcolor import colored
import sys
import serial
import struct

class usbComm:
    'USB Communication Class'
    def __init__(self, Port):
        'Try to open the port and initialize the object'
        try:
            self.PortObj = serial.Serial(Port, 9600, timeout=1)
        except OSError as e:
            print(colored("ERROR: Failed to open {0}\nERROR: {1}".format(Port, str(e)), "red"))
            exit(1)
        print(colored("Connected to " + self.PortObj.name, "green"))

    def SendData(self, Data):
        'Send raw data to 3D Printer'
        'Returns total number of bytes written'
        return self.PortObj.write(Data)

    def ReadData(self, count):
        return self.PortObj.read(count)

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.PortObj.close()
            print(colored("Closed", "green"))
        except AttributeError as e:
            print(colored("ERROR: " + str(e), "red"))

def main():
    print(colored("+-----------------------------------+", "blue"))
    print(colored("| 3D Printer USB Communication Tool |", "blue"))
    print(colored("+-----------------------------------+", "blue"))

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print(colored("ERROR: Invalid number of arguments.", "red"))
        print("Usage: main.py <PORT> <DATA>")
        exit(1)

    usbCommObj = usbComm(sys.argv[1])
    print(usbCommObj.SendData(b"\x7e"))
    print(usbCommObj.ReadData(1))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So i should receive "~" But the output is:

Connected to /dev/ttyACM10
1
b'\xff'
Closed

At my microcontroller i have the code:

```
    while(1){
        // char s[7] = "";
        // for(int i = 0; i< 7; i++){
        //    s[i] = fgetc(USBtty0);
        // }
        // for(int i = 0; i< 7; i++){
        //    fputc(s[i], USBtty0);
        // }
        int c = fgetc(USBtty0);
        //c=0x7e;
        if (c==0x7e)PORTB.OUT |= PIN1_bm;
        fputc(c, USBtty0);
        // switch(c) {
        //     case 0:{
        //         fputc(c, USBtty0);
        //         break;
        //     }
        //     case 1:{
        //         //if(motor(10000,0,0)==1)
        //         fputc(c, USBtty0);
        //         break;
        //     }
        // }
        if(!(PORTB.IN & PIN6_bm))
            PORTB.OUT |= PIN1_bm;
        else
            PORTB.OUT &= ~PIN1_bm;
        USBPoll();
    }
```

Some time ago i could get an working connection, what did I wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the microcontroller uses the same baudrate as your computer?

Comment: Yes, and if i receive data from miccroocontroller it works

Comment: First be sure that python script is working. disconnect AVR and reconnect TX and RX on output from PC. then try transmit from this script and listen what you transmitting.

Comment: Ahh sorry i already solved it